# Most efficient way to index an array column to allow for selecting rows containing a value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, indexing

Say I have a table like this:

```sql
create table mytable (
   mycol text[]
)
```

And I want to select all rows where `mycol` contains `"hello"`. I can think of two ways to do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 'hello'=any(mycol);
--or
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol && '{hello}';
```

I know for the second option I can use GIN indexes (which allow for array options), and I'm pretty sure for the first I would use a BTREE (or maybe a HASH?).

So my question is this: If I only need to check the membership of a single item, which method with what index is most efficient for a table with millions of rows?

Comment: Run the queries with [`explain`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-explain/) and it will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd, with a GIN index.

The first one can't use either a btree or a hash index in an efficient way.  It can use a btree index, but only as a skinny copy of the table.

You might be confusing this with the reverse situation, where the column is before the ANY (and is a scalar) and the literal is inside the ANY.  This one *can* use the btree.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable_scalar WHERE mycol =any('{hello,goodbye}');
```

A good way to see how efficient something will be is often just to try it with fake data but of a vaguely realistic size:

```
insert into mytable select ARRAY[md5(random()::text),md5(random()::text)] from generate_series(1,1500000);
```